# How to get URL attach with button?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping this website [Click here](https://playlists.bubbleapps.io/playlists) here is button in each record that use java-script to open Spotify page. I want to get URL of  that Spotify page using python. I used Selenium and Beautiful-soup for scraping other content but i can not find way to **scrape** that url. Please any one can tell me how to do that.

**Edited:**

I am trying this.

```
browser1.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/button').click()
link = '{}'.format(browser1.current_url)
browser1.back()
```

First i click button go to that page and then get url and then come back to main web page. Its taking lots of Because when it come back to orginal web site its on first page then i have to go to that page number that i am scraping.

Comment: Can you please share with us what you tried? Like a piece of code?

Comment: Yes of course i edited the question.

Comment: @2437141 sir please can you help me?/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below solution with relative xpath

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://playlists.bubbleapps.io/playlists")
print driver.current_url

element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='bubble-element GroupItem group-item entry-1']//button[@class='fa fa-spotify inner-element bubble-element clickable-element']")))
element.click()
#     print(elements)
# driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='bubble-element GroupItem group-item entry-1']//button[@class='fa fa-spotify inner-element bubble-element clickable-element']").click()
print driver.current_url
```

**Output:**

```
https://playlists.bubbleapps.io/playlists
https://open.spotify.com/playlist/5rl5QaWjWtEPv9a057w3qc
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I am trying kind of similar solution but it taking me lots of time because its single page website when i came back to orginal URL it on first page of  website then i have to go that page where i am currently scraping by click next button. And website has lots of pages.

Comment: Is there any other solution, like getting url attached with that button.

Comment: Mate if you observed that button there is no link present with it and as per your above question i think I have provided answer to you